# Discord.js - My bot is unable to send messages in one specific channel, and has no problem in other channels

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have a Discord bot programmed in Discord.js and it works absolutely fine for sending messages in any channel it can access.

However, on one specific channel on one specific server, it is unable to send messages, react, or do anything at all. The bot has Administrator-level access and I have gone in and checked every single permission on, and yet it still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

So, based on what's provided, I can't really give a concrete answer -- especially without an error message. However, I can take guesses. So here's my biggest guess:

How are you fetching the channel? Are you using the `GuildChannelManager#fetch()` method, or are you using the `GuildChannelManager#cache.get()` method (`guild.channels.fetch` or `guild.channels.cache.get`)?

Are you getting it by name, ID, etc.? If by name, ensure you've got only one channel with that name, and that you're fetching the channel from the **guild**, not the **client**. If by ID, ensure you're using the correct ID.